# Keep state in sync with fast occuring events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sockets, react-hooks

I made a custom hooks keep track of a state variable that is based on the amount of socket events received.
When I test by sending 10 simultaneous events the result of the state variable total is 6 or 7 or 8 not the expected 10.

```js
const useSocketAmountReceivedState = (event: string): number => {
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        Socket.on(event, () => {
            console.log(total);
            setTotal(total + 1);
        });

        return (): void => {
            Socket.off(event);
        };
    });

    return total;
}
```

The logs of run look something like

```
0
1
1
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
```

`Socket` in the example above is implementation around websocket.

So I can deduct that total is not updated fast enough, but what is the best pattern to handle this sort of behaviour ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but try: `setTotal(prevTotal => prevTotal + 1);`

Comment: Socket.on event has to be outside the useEffect function

Comment: Please make sure you don't run the useEffect() at every render. For that, add an empty array for the second param in useEffect().

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies

@EdsonMagombe That did the trick, could you maybe explain to me why ?
Is it because the `useEffect` will only "update" `total` again once the state changed ?

Comment: No. Its simple. You are creating an event Socket.on every time useEffect is called. So You are having many Socket.on printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague came with this solution.
Using a reference for which as it is a reference is not enclosed.

```
const useSocketAmountReceivedState = (event: string): number => {
    const count = useRef(0);
    const [state, setState] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        Socket.on(event, () => {
            count.current++;
            setState(count.current);
        });

        return (): void => {
            Socket.off(event);
        };
    }, []);

    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting an empty array as the second argument in the hook. You don't want this to register an event each time the component renders.

```
const useSocketAmountReceivedState = (event: string): number => {
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        Socket.on(event, () => {
            console.log(total);
            setTotal(total + 1);
        });

        return (): void => {
            Socket.off(event);
        };
    }, [total]);

    return total;
}
```

UPDATE:

***I made an update to my initial answer, and added Total into the dependency array of the React Hook.***

Note that the second argument, aka dependency array. It is an array that accepts state or prop. And it instructs React to run this hook each time any of the elements in the dependency array changes.

If you pass an empty array, then the hook will only be run at initial load, after the component mounts.

In your example, if you pass an empty array, it creates a closure. Hence, the total value will always be the initial value.

So you can pass **Total** into the dependency array, which will invoke the useEffect() to run only when Total value changes. In your example, where there is no dependency array passed to the second argument, the useEffect() will run every single time, which is not what we want.

Comment: By looking at the question I would say there's a possibility the asker isn't really sure how the dependencies work, so it might be worth updating your answer to explain this, and also explain that the useEffect function will execute every time the dependency changes and that almost all the time (at least in my experience) not putting any dependencies (i.e. a square bracket) will cause the useEffect to just keep executing itself over and over again indefinitely.

Comment: Added more details :)

Comment: I just tested this approach.  

In this scenario I believe the `0` or the initial value of `total` is enclosed in the callback. So this results in total being updated to 1 each time.

Comment: This has the same problem as the original, total is not "changed" as frequently as it should, lagging behind.

Answer (score 2):

Socket.on event has to be outside the useEffect function

```
const useSocketAmountReceivedState = (event: string): number => {
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    Socket.on(event, () => {
        console.log(total);
        setTotal(total + 1);
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        return (): void => {
            Socket.off(event);
        };
    }, []);

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Although this kinda works it is also calling the `on` function a lot. Too much actually rebinding it constantly which is a huge performance hit and doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: The note is that you have to set it in a place that it is called once only. If you use your useSocketAmountReceivedState many times. That will multiply the event

Comment: So you have to remove it to somewhere where you make sure it runs once only. If you share your code i may help

Comment: ```
const Demo = (): ReactElement => {

    const topicUpdates = useSocketAmountReceivedState('topic-test');
    
    return (
        <div>
            {topicUpdates}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Would you suggest wrapping it ?

Comment: No. Its ok. Have you got a main class? in the same file?